# How to use any type in a function?

Tags: c#, .net, function

The recursive function checks the looping of the members of the class hierarchy. It works, but I want to make it common to all similar objects in the program. How do I use the  parameter in this case?

```
private bool CheckReferenceLoop(Organization Object, List<Organization> OrganizationsStack, Data.DataContext db)
    {
        bool HaveLoop = false;
        if (OrganizationsStack.Find(a => a.Id == Object.Id) != null)
        {
            HaveLoop = true;
        }
        else
        {
            OrganizationsStack.Add(Object);
            Object.GetChildItems(db);
            Object.ChildItems.ForEach(delegate (Organization ChildItem)
            {
                if (!HaveLoop)
                {
                    HaveLoop = CheckReferenceLoop(ChildItem, OrganizationsStack, db);
                }
            });
        }
        return HaveLoop;
    }
```

Comment: What is common between all objects?

Comment: Is it the `Organization`-class you want to change? You can change the signature to something like  `CheckReferenceLoop<T>(T Object, List<T> OrganizationsStack, Data.DataContext db)`. However, you will need a generic interface for the classes that contains methods like `GetChildItems`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I want to make it common to all similar objects in the program

This require that the classes actually are *similiar*. For that we introduce an interface which includes everyting that is *similiar*. Let's call it `ICanHaveReferenceLoop`. The implementation could look like this:

```
public interface ICanHaveReferenceLoop
{
    int Id { get; }
    void GetChildItems(Data.DataContext db);
    IEnumerable<ICanHaveReferenceLoop> ChildItems { get; }
}
```

Make sure that `Organization` and your other classes implements this interface.

```
public class Organization : ICanHaveReferenceLoop
{
    //... your code.
}
```

And then change your method as such:

```
private bool CheckReferenceLoop<T>(T Object, List<T> OrganizationsStack, Data.DataContext db) where T : ICanHaveReferenceLoop
    {
        bool HaveLoop = false;
        if (OrganizationsStack.Find(a => a.Id == Object.Id) != null)
        {
            HaveLoop = true;
        }
        else
        {
            OrganizationsStack.Add(Object);
            Object.GetChildItems(db);
            Object.ChildItems.ForEach(delegate (T ChildItem)
            {
                if (!HaveLoop)
                {
                    HaveLoop = CheckReferenceLoop(ChildItem, OrganizationsStack, db);
                }
            });
        }
        return HaveLoop;
    }
```

Note that `where T` is needed in the end of the signature, or else you will not be able to use `Object.GetChildItems(db);` or `Object.ChildItems.ForEach`.

Comment: I used the parent class `public class ICatalog`. Using your example, I will also change it to interface. Thank you very much for the example!

Comment: @123Иванов it doesn't need to be an interface. It may also be a base class. It will work just as well.

Comment: I think the interface is correct. Expanding your answer for posterity: 
`public interface ICatalog<T>
    {
        T Parent { get; set; }
        List<T> ChildItems { get; set; }
        List<T> GetChildItems(DataContext db);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Try using  at the start of the function, and then use T as the type, like this:

```cs
private bool CheckReferenceLoop<T>(List<T> OrganisationsStack, Data.DataContext db)
```

Then, when calling the function use CheckReferenceLoop()

Comment: Use ```CheckReferenceLoop<type>()``` when calling

Comment: Thanks. Smoksnes gave a detailed answer